# How many strings of $3$ decimal digits have exactly two digits as $4$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I approached the problem in this way :
Fix two $4's$ and then third place can have $10$ ways to choose from {0,1,..,9} and then arrangement= ${10*3!}/2!$ = 30
But , Since we have {$4,4,4$} and {$4,4,0$} as two ways of digits which gives me {$0,4,4$} as one invalid arrangement and all $3$ arrangements of {$4,4,4$} as invalid.
 Therefore total = $30-1-3$=$26$
 Am I missing out something or Including something extra ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$044$ is a string of $3$ decimal digits, so unless the problem explicitly says that leading zeroes are not allowed, I would count it, getting $27$. An easier approach is to note that there are $3$ places for the digit that is not a $4$, and there are $9$ choices for that digit, for a total of $3\cdot 9=27$ strings. (And you can then subtract $1$ for the string $044$ if leading zeroes are not allowed.)

Comment: True, 3-digit strings is asked means we need to consider {0,4,4} as one valid string. I was short of one with the answer , So I raised this. Thanks.

Comment: @user2016963: You’re welcome.

Comment: Do you mind to look at this problem and tell me if there is some other way round to solve , or may be to exclude the repeated cases, please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317607/how-many-strings-of-8-english-letters-are-there-repetition-allowed?noredirect=1#comment2676830_1317607